# Complex C# Linq Algorithm

Tags: c#, algorithm, linq, shortest-path

I have a C# problem to solve. I am creating an application which can determine the shortest route to take. There is a network of ports and the method needs to work out the quickest route to take.

I have got this far with my method but it seems like I am duplicating code and the possible routes could go on forever. Has anyone on got an idea of a better way to test all possibly journeys so I am able to calculate the shortest one ?

```
 public int ShortestJourneyTime(string startPort, string endPort)
    {
        int shortJourneyTime = 0;
        var possStartRoutes = RouteData.Where(p => p.Key[0] == startPort);

        if (possStartRoutes.Count() <= 0)
            throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format("{0} : Start port is invalid", startPort));

        foreach (var p in possStartRoutes)
        {
            int currentJourneyTime = p.Value;

            var possRoutes2 = RouteData.Where(p2 => p2.Key[0] == p.Key[1]);

            foreach (var p2 in possRoutes2)
            {
                if (p2.Key[1] == endPort)
                {
                    currentJourneyTime += p2.Value;
                    if (shortJourneyTime > currentJourneyTime || shortJourneyTime == 0)
                        shortJourneyTime = currentJourneyTime;
                }
                else
                {
                    var possRoutes3 = RouteData.Where(p3 => p3.Key[0] == p2.Key[1]);
                }
            }
        }

        return shortJourneyTime;
    }
```

The port data is stored like below

```
  Dictionary<List<string>, int>  testData = new Dictionary<List<string>, int>();

        List<string> routeOne = new List<string>() { "Buenos Aires", "New York" };
        testData.Add(routeOne, 6);
```

Comment: Your problem description is _"I need to try and refactor it"_. What exactly is your question?

Comment: I believe it is the fact he has too keep writing more and more code (he stopped at `possRoutes3`), I think he wants to know how to make the function work without having to write code for each tier of route.

Comment: @Scott this isn't Jeopardy, but: what is recursion?

Comment: @CodeCaster I was purposely being vague in hopes to not answer the question in a comment. But yea, I think the OP wants to be told how to rewrite his code to be recursive.

Comment: Have a look at the links in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10874533/106159).

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Yes exactly the code does not really work

Comment: @user you're making the same mistake as in your question. _"Does not really work"_ does not really invite others to help you. Explain what you expect this to do, what it does and what you have tried to resolve those differences. See [ask].

Comment: @user1826413 Go read the duplicate question and look at the example of Dijkstra algorithm.

Comment: Why is *using Linq* of any relevance in this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As people suggested Dijkstra algorithm. Here is the algorithm for your needs. I kept your data structure `Dictionary<List<string>, int>` so you can still work with it. But i changed the data structure inside the algorithm and choosed more suitable data structure to make algorithm easier.

The idea is to get all possible paths from start to the end. Then take the shortest path as result. Note that the passed paths should not be duplicated means if we pass `New York` we should not pass over it again otherwise we fall into infinite loop.

The return type of this method is `Tuple<List<string>, int>`. where `List<string>` is the shortest path holding ports in order and `int` is the length of this path. You can access them with properties `Item1` and `Item2`.

For instance The shortest path from `Buenos Aires` to `Liverpool` is this list of string `"Buenos Aires","Casablanca","Liverpool"` with length of `8` days.

Note that This method returns null if nothing was found. You can throw exception if you want. Just uncomment where i commented `throw expetion`

Paths in this method are type of `Tuple<string, string, int>`. `Item1` is the start port. `Item2` is end port and `Item3` is the length between these two ports.

```
public Tuple<List<string>, int> TakeShortestJourney(string startPort, string endPort)
{
    if (startPort == endPort) // just for special case when user puts same start and end port.
    {
        return new Tuple<List<string>, int>(new List<string>(){startPort}, 0);
    }

    // convert from Dictionary<List<string>, int> into List<Tuple<string, string, int>>
    var t = RouteData.Select(x => new Tuple<string, string, int>(x.Key[0], x.Key[1], x.Value));
    var allPaths = new List<Tuple<string, string, int>>(t);

    // This will hold all possible short paths.
    var passedPaths = new List<Tuple<List<string>, int>>();

    // create a recursion method to do the search and fill the passedPaths.
    Action<List<string>, string, int> getPath = null;
    getPath = (list, start, length) =>
    {
        list.Add(start);

        foreach (
            var currentRoad in
                allPaths.Where(x => !list.Contains(x.Item2) && x.Item1 == start).OrderBy(x => x.Item3))
        {
            int newLength = length + currentRoad.Item3; // calculate new length.

            if (currentRoad.Item2 == endPort)
            {
                list.Add(currentRoad.Item2);
                passedPaths.Add(new Tuple<List<string>, int>(list, newLength));
                break;
            }

            if (passedPaths.Any(x => x.Item2 < newLength)) break;

            getPath(new List<string>(list), currentRoad.Item2, newLength);
        }
    };

    // start search with initial empty list and 0 length. start from startPort
    getPath(new List<string>(), startPort, 0);

    // Take the shortest path from passed paths.
    var shortestPath = passedPaths.OrderBy(x=> x.Item2).FirstOrDefault();

    if (shortestPath == null) {
    //    throw new ApplicationException("nothing was found");
    }

    return shortestPath;
}
```

Here is example of how to use this method.

```
var shortestPath = TakeShortestJourney("Buenos Aires", "Liverpool");

foreach (var p in shortestPath.Item1) // Item1 holds path
{
    Console.WriteLine(p);
}

Console.WriteLine(shortestPath.Item2); // Item2 holds length
```

**About the recursion Action:**

```
list.Add(start);
```

We do this for each call so we build our path with order.

```
allPaths.Where(x => !list.Contains(x.Item2) && x.Item1 == start).OrderBy(x => x.Item3)
```

This Query will get the paths that start with `start` which is end of previous path (`x.Item1 == start`) but it will not take the paths that already exist in our list to prevent duplicates (`!list.Contains(x.Item2)`). Finally it will order them by `Item3`(length) so we take the shortest first (`OrderBy(x => x.Item3)`).

```
if (currentRoad.Item2 == endPort)
{
    list.Add(currentRoad.Item2);
    passedPaths.Add(new Tuple<List<string>, int>(list, newLength));
    break;
}
```

This will check for end of our path. it happens when `Item2`(end of the current path) is equal to the end port. Finally we add the last item(`Item2`) to the list, we save our list and the final length together inside the `passedPaths`. We break the loop because we know the length after this path would be longer because we already reached the end so its unnecessary to continue for the other paths. (remember that we ordered them by `Item3`)

```
if (passedPaths.Any(x => x.Item2 < newLength)) break;
```

This one is just for further optimization Means if there is any complete path exist and the length of the current path is bigger than that, stop building this path since there is shorter path exist. also because the query was ordered, next items have even longer length so we just return from this path. Based on RouteData this may increase or decrease performance. You can safely remove this part without affecting results.

```
getPath(new List<string>(list), currentRoad.Item2, newLength);
```

Here is the heart of this algorithm! a recursion call. First parameter is the `list` that we are making but we create new reference of it each time so the list remains untouched from recursions and we can continue in our foreach loop. Second parameter `currentRoad.Item2` is the end of the current path which will be start of the next path. Last parameter `newLength`, we need this when we save final path in `Tuple<List<string>, int>`.

Comment: Thank you for you explanation it was extremely helpful! @M.kazemAkhgary

Comment: @SOreadytohelp if the Start & End port are the same could it be possible to still find all possible routes back to the original port ?

Comment: No. because this method is preventing duplicates. so when you pass over first port it will never be able to pass over it again to actually finish the path . but you can fix this by removing start port. so end port is not a duplicate. @user1826413

Comment: @user1826413 note that this method will almost finishes the path for example `Buenos Aires => casablanca => cape town` but it wont take `Buenos Aires` again because first `Buenos Aires` duplicates. You can fix this by changing `!list.Contains(x.Item2)` into `!list.Skip(1).Contains(x.Item2)` . also remember to remove the first `if (startPort == endPort)...` statement for this special case

Comment: @SOreadytohelp  Amazing thanks a lot! much appreaticed

Comment: glad it helped! :) @user1826413